# $\left(\sqrt{A}\right)^{2}=A$ prove that $A$ and $\sqrt{A}$ have the same eigen spaces

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Hi I'm given a symmetric matrix $A\in M_{n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
with all positive eigen values $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n}$ i need to find a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$ and also $A$ and $B$ have the same eigen spaces, since $A$ is symmetric it is orthogonal diagonalizable, so i know that $A=PDP^{t}$ where P orthogonal and D diagonal matrix, I defined $B=PD^{\frac{1}{2}}P$ and i get that $B^2=A$ but I'm struggling to prove that B and A have the same eigen spaces, I've managed to prove that every eigen vector in the eigen space $V_{u_{i}}$ where $u_{i}=\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}$ is in $V_{\lambda_{i}}$ but i cannot prove the other way

Comment: than how should i define B ?

Comment: Your $B$ is fine. The $Pe_i$ form a basis of eigenvectors both for $A$ and for $B$, and the eigenspacevof $A$ for $\lambda$ is the eigenspace of $B$ for $\sqrt\lambda$. - One *can* find different $B$ that might not work by picking mixes of $\pm\sqrt\lambda$, so that the eigenspaces of $B$ are “finer” than those of $A$, but by consistent choice of positive roots, all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the diagonal of $D$ is $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ in order. Let $v_i$ be the $i^{th}$ column of $P$, so $v_i$ are the linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. Thus, $Bv_i=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}v_i=PD^{1/2}e_i=P\sqrt{\lambda_i}e_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}v_i$. Since eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue in the list $\{v_i\}$ are a basis of the corresponding eigenspace of $A$, we see that the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$ is a subset of the eigenspace of $B$ corresponding to $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$.